# What are the names and the function of these aircraft components?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image: What are the names and the function of these aircraft components?]

These images were taken from a Cessna 150 aircraft containing a Continental O-200 engine.

Comment: Related, in case you don't have all answers: [C150 service manual](http://rob.com/matt/manuals/150_sm_69.pdf). After 1976, [this one](https://www.redskyventures.org/doc/cessna-maintenance-manuals/Cessna_150_1969-1976_MM_D971-3-13.pdf).

Comment: Are you the pilot, owner or mechanic?

Answer (score 2):

1 - nutplate holding something on the other side of the firewall

2 - starter or master contactor (a relay operated by low-current signal from cockpit switch)

4 - positive heavy-gauge cable to battery or starter

5 and 6 might be the alternator voltage regulator to hold the output voltage at 14.4V

10 - oil filter to remove carbon and other crud from oil

11 and 23 - magneto to provide carefully-timed high voltage pulses at for ignition

12 - alternator to charge battery and run electric instruments / radios

14 - vacuum pump to power gyroscopic flight instruments

15 - carburetor to meter air and fuel

21 - crankcase vent (?) to prevent blow-by gases from forcing oil out of the engine

22 - fuel strainer drain valve to drain water / crud from low point in fuel system

Better pictures would help to identify the other parts!

Comment: Are you sure it's a 12v (14.4) system and not a 28v one?

Comment: @RonBeyer C150s have 12V systems by design. I *suppose* someone could change out of r a 28V system if they *really* wanted to.

Comment: I believe 2 is specifically the starter solenoid. I believe the master solenoid is below the battery box.

Answer (score 1):

```
1 - nutplate holding something on the other side of the firewall

2 - starter or master contactor (a relay operated by low-current signal from cockpit switch)

4 - positive heavy-gauge cable to battery or starter

5 and 6 might be the alternator voltage regulator to hold the output voltage at 14.4V

10 - oil filter to remove carbon and other crud from oil

11 and 23 - magneto to provide carefully-timed high voltage pulses at for ignition

12 - alternator to charge battery and run electric instruments / radios

14 - vacuum pump to power gyroscopic flight instruments

15 - carburetor to meter air and fuel

21 - crankcase vent (?) to prevent blow-by gases from forcing oil out of the engine

22 - fuel strainer drain valve to drain water / crud from low point in fuel system
```

And to fill in the missing items:

3 - Rubber nipple protecting the energize conductor for the item 1 contactor

6 - Over voltage sensor (shuts off alternator if voltage is too high)

7 - Vacuum hose to cockpit (feeds air powered instruments)

8 - Avionics cooling duct inlet.

9 - static pressure port.

13 - left side exhaust muffler / cabin heat exchanger.

16 - Induction air filter

17 - Induction air box including carb heat valve.

18 - Engine data plate.

19 - Spark plug.

20 - Air inlet for cabin heat system.

23 - Right magneto.

24 - Oil filler cap.

25 - Rubber nipple protecting battery positive wire terminal.

26 - Battery box.

Comment: I believe 6 is not an over-voltage sensor but the radio noise filter.

Comment: @JonathanWalters You are correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- 8 may be the AC system intake
- 9 is the static port for the pressure-based instruments
- 15 looks like a fuse box
- 18 is the engine information plate
- 19 is a spark plug

Comment: What kind of Cessna 150 has air conditioning?  Probably just cabin air intake

Comment: 8 is an avionics vent intake; 15 is the Carburetor; 18 is more properly called the engine data plate;